# python: How to remove values from 2 lists based on what's in 1 list

Tags: python

I have 2 lists of numbers, one called `xVar` and the other called `yVar`.  I will use these 2 elements to plot X and Y values on a graph.  They both have the same number of elements.

Normally, I would just plot

```
ax.scatter(xVar,yVar,s=2,color='tomato');
```

I want to remove data from `yVar` that are over a certain value, for example all data that have a `yVar` value over `100`, but I also want to remove the associated `xVar` value.  Can somebody suggest a way to create 2 new variables that remove all values in `yVar` over `100` and the `xVar` values associated with them?  Then I can just substitute `xVar` & `yVar` in my plotting line to the new variables.

Thanks again All,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Whenever you want to do something to the corresponding values of two (or more) lists, that's what [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is for. It gives you one list, of the corresponding values for each index.

So, in this case, `zip` the two lists together, then filtered the zipped list, then unzip them (with `zip` again, as the documentation explains):

```
xVar, yVar = zip(*((x, y) for x, y in zip(xVar, yVar) if y <= 100))
```

If this is confusing, let me show it step by step:

```
>>> xVar = [1, 200, 300, 10]
>>> yVar = [150, 100, 50, 200]
>>> xyVar = zip(xVar, yVar)
>>> xyVar
[(1, 150), (200, 100), (300, 50), (10, 500)]
>>> xyFiltered = [(x, y) for x, y in xyVar if y <= 100]
>>> xyFiltered
[(200, 100), (300, 50)]
>>> xVar, yVar = zip(*xyFiltered)
[(200, 300), (100, 50)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Without writing the code, find the index for the y you want to remove, save the index, remove the y value, then remove the x value at the same index number.

Comment: But there be tricks/gremlins when removing multiple elements (e.g. when removal is during iteration of the list) this way ..

Comment: @user2246674: Just one trick, really: You have to reverse-sort the indices before removing them. But yeah, it's really easy to forget to do that, or get it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Find indices which correspond to data you want to retain:

```
ind = [i for i in range(len(yVar)) if yVar[i] < 100]
```

And use only those points:

```
yVar = [yVar[i] for i in ind]
xVar = [xVar[i] for i in ind]
```

Comment: you might want to check out [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)