# Why can't I write this code in the usual for statement?

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator

I just read a post here about how to filter values from two lists.[python: How to remove values from 2 lists based on what's in 1 list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017638/python-how-to-remove-values-from-2-lists-based-on-whats-in-1-list)

I tried to write some code myself using `for` and `zip`, but the result is wrong, can anyone help me understand this?

```
xVar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
yVar = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77]

z = zip(xVar, yVar)
zFiltered = [(x, y) for x, y in z if y < 50]
print zFiltered # Correct, prints [(1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33), (4, 44)]

for (x, y) in z:
    if y > 50:
        z.remove((x, y))

print z # Wrong, prints [(1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33), (4, 44), (6, 66)]
```

Why is this happening? I tried to use `pdb` and found that after `z.remove((5, 55))`, `(x, y)`'s value is `(7, 77)`, `(6, 66)` is skiped, I assume that `for` is assigning `(x, y)` via indexs, removing `(5, 55)` will violate the original index, if so, how can I do the same thing here with `for` statements? and is there any other pitfalls here?

Comment: Don't change a list while iterating over it.

Comment: use copy module : import copy, for (x,y) in z ---> for (x,y) in copy.copy(z).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you remove an item from a list while iterating over it, its internal structure gets out of whack, and items are skipped.  The easy way around this issue is to make a copy of the list by adding `[:]`.

```
for (x, y) in z[:]:
    ...
```

Now you can make changes to the original list as it is not being iterated over.

Answer (score 3):

Try this list comprehension which will select elements in your zipped list based on a condition (basically the opposite of removing elements from the list that do not satisfy this condition, but it will yield the same results).

```
z = [(x, y) for (x, y) in z if y <= 50]
```

If you want to delete elements in a list while iterating over it, you must iterate backwards because every time you delete an item in a list, all of the elements that have higher indexes in the list get shifted downward to lower indexes.

You can do such an iteration like so:

```
for i in xrange(len(z) -1, -1, -1):
    if z[i][1] > 50:
        z.remove(z[i])
```

Comment: The first approach is pythonic =D

Comment: @justhalf yup, it's clean...but I still like to be a complete dork and do it the second way sometimes xD